# ld: library not found for -lReactNativeNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React-Native and I'm trying to figure out how to run the project on iOS. I know this error means I need to add the library `.xcodeproj` to XCode, but where is this file located? I'm using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started.html) and I installed it with yarn and after I have run the command `react-native link`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need to use react-native link in order to use react-navigation, because it just uses js. Did you try to remove node_modules folder and install modules again?

Comment: Wait I think I get what's going on, I've added previously https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-ios but removed it with yarn and now I want to use react-navigation instead, seems like it is still linked somewhere in XCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a previous installation of `react-native-navigation`, which uses native code.

First you need to unlink this library:

```
react-native unlink react-native-navigation
```

Note: You need to have the source code of the `react-native-navigation` package in order to unlink. If you already removed from you package.json, you need to install again to unlink.

After unlink, you can remove the `react-native-navigation` and just move forward using the react-navigation library, which does not need to link native code.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Rafael's answer, I previously added React-Native-Navigation and yes it was still linked in the Link Binaries With Libraries, so I deleted it, here's a picture showing which library to remove [image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using react-native-navigation and still got this issue consider
updating IOS Target Deployment to version 11 in Xcode Build Settings

from
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/6734#issuecomment-720735261